# tf.constant_initializer() vs tf.global_variables_initializer()

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following code from [this](https://jacobbuckman.com/post/tensorflow-the-confusing-parts-1/) website, what's the role of `tf.constant_initializer(0.)` and `tf.global_variables_initializer()`? Why do we need two initializers?

```
import tensorflow as tf

### build the graph
## first set up the parameters
m = tf.get_variable("m", [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.))
b = tf.get_variable("b", [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

## then set up the computations
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
output_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

x = input_placeholder
y = output_placeholder
y_guess = m * x + b

loss = tf.square(y - y_guess)

## finally, set up the optimizer and minimization node
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-3)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

### start the session
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
```

The original post I link has an explanation that goes:

> The answer lies in the split between sessions and graphs. We’ve set
>   the initializer property of get_variable to point at our
>   const_init_node, but that just added a new connection between nodes in
>   the graph. We haven’t done anything about the root of the exception:
>   the memory associated with the variable node (which is stored in the
>   session, not the graph!) is still set to “null”. We need the session
>   to tell the const_init_node to actually update the variable.

... which still seems confusing as, in that case, why do we need the `tf.constant_initializer(0.)` at all? We might as well just leave our `m` and `b` uninitialized until we run `tf.global_variables_initializer()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you want to create a Tensorflow graph and train it from scratch. Therefore, all of the `tf.Variable` in your TF Graph will be initialized randomly. For example, in the code bellow, the `tf.Variable` will be initialized with values from a normal distribution.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.get_variable(name="random", shape=[1, 5] initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(x))
    # [[-1.1984633  -0.42527035 -1.020795   -0.7023787   0.22350429]]
```

Now, let us assume that you again want to create a TF Graph and train it from scratch. However, right now, for some weird reason, you know the exact values that you want to use for some of the `tf.Variable` in your graph. Therefore:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.get_variable(name="constant", shape=[1,5], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=[[1,2,3,4,5]]))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(x))
    # [[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]]
```

you initialized those `tf.Variable` with a the values you wish.

As for the distinction between `tf.global_variables_initializer` and `tf.constant_initializer`, they are something completely different:

- `tf.global_variables_initializer` is an operation that you execute to initialize all variables in your graph. It doesn't matter whether the variables will get initialized with `tf.constant_initializer`, `tf.random_normal_initializer` or `tf.glorot_uniform_initializer`. You just pass that operation to a `tf.Session` so that the graph variables will get initialized.
- `tf.constant_initializer` on the other hand, is just an initializer that you pass to the `tf.Variable` of your graph. Then, when a `tf.Session` runs the operation `tf.global_variables_initializer`, the TF Graph will use the `tf.constant_initializer` to initialize the corresponding `tf.Variable` with the constant values provided.

Answer (score 2):

The two are entirely different. The `constant_initializer` is basically an "instruction" how the variable should be initialized *once this is actually done*. I.e., whether it should use constant values, random uniform values, random normal values...
Passing this does not mean that the variable will be initialized with constant values at that time. If you don't pass an initializer, `get_variable` uses a default (`glorot_uniform`, I believe).

`global_variables_initializer`, on the other hand, is an op that will actually *perform* the initialization once it is run inside a session -- this will then call the execute the initializers you passed to the variables when you created them. You *always* need to run an op to initialize variables, since as mentioned, just passing the initializers in the constructors doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 2):

[This TensorFlow Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variables#initializing_variables) about initializing variables might be helpful.

And below three things are from TensorFlow site and also useful.
[`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable): Gets an existing variable with these parameters or create a new one.
[`tf.constant_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/constant): Initializer that generates tensors with constant values.
[`tf.global_variables_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/global_variables): Returns an Op that initializes global variables.

---

To put it simply, the role of `tf.constant_initializer` is to generate constant values.
The role of `tf.global_variables_initializer` is to initialize variables. In TensorFlow, you should initialize variables before creating graphs and sessions. Therefore you have to use `tf.global_variables_initializer` when using variables.

---

<s>Actually, in your code, you don't have to use `tf.constant_initializer` because `tf.get_variable` uses default initializer as `glorot_uniform_initializer`.</s>

But you should use `tf.global_variables_initializer` because `tf.get_variable` gets an variables or creates an variables.

---

Example code 1: If you do not use `tf.global_variables_initializer` then yon encounter an error message.

```
import tensorflow as tf

m = tf.get_variable("m", [])
b = tf.get_variable("b", [])

y = m + b

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(y)
```

```
# Example code 1 result

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value m
     [[{{node m/read}}]]
```

Example code 2: You don't have to use `tf.constant_initializer`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

m = tf.get_variable("m", [])
b = tf.get_variable("b", [])
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

y = m + b

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
sess.run(y)
```

```
# Example code 2 result

Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
0.43568623
```

---

Finally, even if you use `tf.constant_initializer` in `tf.get_variable` you should use `tf.global_variables_initializer`. The reason is that `tf.get_variable` is a variable. So you initialize variables before `tf.Session` by using `tf.global_variables_initializer`.

Maybe you can think of `initializer` in `tf.get_variable`(e.g `tf.constant_initializer`, `glorot_uniform_initializer`) as initializing value by some kind of distributions when initializing variables by using `tf.global_variables_initializer`.

Comment: IMHO this point you are making is wrong "Actually, in your code, you don't have to use `tf.constant_initializer` because `tf.get_variable` uses default initializer as `tf.glorot_uniform_initializer`.". The point of using a constant initializer is if you want to fix some of the `tf.Variable` values at the start. Assume that I want to perform an experiment where I want to measure the convergence speed of a model where all weights are initialized randomly except for one weight matrix, which is initialized with all values being `99.99`. Then you need `tf.constant_initializer`.

Comment: @gorjan, thanks for your comment and advice. I truly missed the thing you pointed out. Thank you again.